# Doubts about the functioning of a tf/keras net

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression, data-science

I'm studying quantile regression and I have some problem to understand how works the net below:

```
    z = tf.keras.layers.Input((len(features),), name="Patient")
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="d1")(z)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="d2")(x)
    
    p1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="p1")(x)
    p2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="p2")(x)
    preds = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + tf.cumsum(x[1], axis=1),
                                   name="preds")([p1, p2])
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(z, preds)
```

In particular, I don't understand the last layer "preds" when Lambda is used: I know how the lambda function works in python, but I don't understand how the Lambda layer combines the input tensor. I hope that someone can help me to understand this.
The net is largely used in a lot of notebooks in Kaggle competition "osic pulmonary fibrosis progression"

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you having difficulties understanding what lambda functions in Python are? Or do you have a question specific to Keras? Are you getting unexpected results? What is the context of the example you have provided? Have you copied it from somewhere?

Comment: @tomanizer I've just modified the post :) . The principal problem is that I don't understand how input tensor are combined

Answer (score 1):

> In the line:
>
> ```
> preds = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + tf.cumsum(x[1], axis=1),
>                                name="preds")([p1, p2])
> ```
>
> The input to Lambda layer is `[p1, p2]`. So `x = [p1, p2]`. Thus,
> `x[0] = p1`, `x[1] = p2`.
>
> Thus the operation it does is `x[0] + tf.cumsum(x[1], axis=1)` i.e. `p1 + tf.cumsum(p2, axis=1)`. You could
> refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/cumsum), about the `tf.cumsum()` function.

Hope this clears your doubts. If you have any more, feel free to ask in comments.

Comment: Oh thanks! I've another question after your reply: axis in cumsum is 1 because input tensor shape is (batch size, dimension of p1 / p2)? if it is so the result of this layer is simply the sum of p1 + cumulative sum of p2? And why a lot of people use this solution and don't predict directly the result for regression?

Comment: shape of p1, p2 and pred all are (batch_size, 3) (3, because of Dense layer). yes,the result of this layer is simply the sum of p1 + cumulative sum of p2, but to use this as keras model, you need to add this in lambda layer.

Comment: Maybe Its the need of the model to use cumsum(). Like for images you use Conv2D, for text, you use LSTM, GRU, etc. So for directly predicting using regression/Dense, you need a couple of extra Dense layers, so it simplifies the task

Comment: Without knowing the reason to use the model, one cannot explain why it is used there